# Ruby method which is running after method is defined

Tags: ruby, class, oop

Let say I have a `class Alex`.

```
class AB < Alex
  some_definition_here # it changes some class variables
end
```

My question is: is there anything like `self.included` for classes which is executed only after class is defined? I want to get access to class variables only after some class variables has been changed.

Comment: The name for "anything like self.included" is "object lifecycle hook".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. But it’s a bit tricky, since there is no notion of “class defined” due to open classes concept in ruby.

What you are looking for is [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/TracePoint.html). Possible usage:

```
  TracePoint.new(:end) do |tp|
    if tp.self.name == 'AB'
      # DO SOME STUFF
      # at this very moment class was closed with end for the 1st time
      tp.disable
    end
  end.enable
```